# Flash reverse timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Worked with flash cs6 and as3.

I wanted to make menu like this [link](http://themeforest.net/item/kappe-full-screen-portfolio-blog-wp-theme/full_screen_preview/6854128). When `mouse_over` on the menu, the blue rectangle moves to the right; and when `mouse_up`, the animation reversed.

I made the blue rectangle in a movieclip `menuBlueHome`. There, I made the rectangle moves from left to right (from frame 1 to 10). At frame 10, I made action script:

```
stop();
```

I was still working with home menu when I faced this problem. When I hover the home menu, the blue rectangle moves to the right and reversed straightaway before `mouse_up`. Here is the code outside the mc:

```
var menuBlueHome: MovieClip;
menuBlueHome.stop();
var direct: String;

btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,onOverHome);
btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,onLeaveHome);
btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClickHome);

function onOverHome(e:MouseEvent):void{
    androidHome.visible = true;
    menuBlueHome.play();
}
function onLeaveHome(e:MouseEvent):void{
    androidHome.visible = false;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrameHome);
}
function onClickHome(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}

function onFrameHome(event:Event):void {
    if(menuBlueHome.currentFrame > 9) {
        direct = "backward";
    }
    var backAmount:Number = menuBlueHome.currentFrame -1;
    if(direct == "backward") {
        menuBlueHome.gotoAndStop(backAmount);
    }
}
```

Did I make something wrong with the code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
function onLeaveHome(e:MouseEvent):void{

    androidHome.visible = false;

    menuBlueHome.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameHome);

    menuBlueHome.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameHome);

}

function onFrameHome(event:Event):void {

    var backAmount:Number = menuBlueHome.currentFrame - 1;

    menuBlueHome.gotoAndStop(backAmount);

    if(backAmount == 1) menuBlueHome.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameHome);

}
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9pbLM_BascZXNhY1BwSXdmR1U/view?usp=sharing) you have and example.

But, I recommend you to do your code more dynamic, here you have [another example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9pbLM_BascX0xJWHpSSFFEOWM/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. It works! But, I prefer the non-dynamic code, it's more simple.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. If you are satisfied with my answer, consider upvote it. Regards. ;)

Comment: I really want to upvote your answer. But sorry, my rep is still 3 (I'm a newbie here since yesterday). I need 12 more, so I can vote. >.<

Comment: Don't worry. I understand ;)
By the other hand, the dynamic code is more verbose but is more maintainable and more easy to extend it, think about this tasks: 1 - change the color of all buttons (only need to change one number). 2 - change the size of all buttons (only need to change one number). 3 - Adding three more buttons (only need to add three lines of code). I don't know if you follow me ;)